# Как выполнить две программы одновременно в терминале?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

Хочу что бы одновременно компилирывался код и в это же время играла музыка.
при вводе:

```
g++ *.cpp && ./a.out && apply test.mp3
```

компилится код и пока программа не завершится музыка не включается.

```
apply test.mp3 && g++ *.cpp && ./a.out
```

при таком раскладе то пока не доиграет трек или не нажать ctrl+c код не компилируется

Comment: можно музыку запустить в бекграунде - `apply test.mp3 &`. Музыка будет играть и консоль будет свободна. можно компилить.

А более красивое средство -использовать screen или tmux.

Comment: @KoVadim ну не надо отвечать в комментариях :(

Comment: просто как по мне, так это не ответ, а так, комментарий.

Comment: @KoVadim мне пишет "usage: apply [-a magic] [-d] [-0123456789] command arguments ...", каких это он от меня еще хочет аргументов?

Comment: а кто его знает. Хотя это мак, а там все могут испоганить. гугл не знает о этом проигрывателе, поэтому, ничего не могу сказать.